# find duplicates from rows and combine row information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
Table 1 structure:

Customer ref, First Name, last name, dateofbirth
 1 , Eric, David, 16-09-1985
 2 , Eric, David, 16-09-1985
 3 , Eric, David, 16-09-1985

Table 2 structure

customer id, customer ref, 
 100, 1
 101, 2
 103, 3
```

I am trying to find the duplicates in table one, and list them in the following format

customer id, firstname, lastname, dateofbirth

I tried the following but get an error that customer id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

```
SELECT a.customerId, a.FirstNAME, a.lastNAME, a.dateofbirth

    FROM dbo.table a
    INNER JOIN dbo.table b
    on a.customerref = b.customerref
    GROUP BY a.FirstNAME, a.lastNAME, a.dateofbirth
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Would appreciate some help

Comment: you either include customerId to group by statement or just delete it from select. Also, If you want to find duplicates of first table, you don't need to join the second table

Comment: SQL (Sorry forgot to mention that).

Comment: Microsoft sql Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if you get any error just let me know

```
SELECT Z.customerId, Y.FirstNAME, Y.lastNAME, Y.dateofbirth FROM
(SELECT FirstNAME, lastNAME, dateofbirth 
FROM table_1
GROUP BY FirstNAME, lastNAME, dateofbirth    
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) X
INNER JOIN table_1 Y
ON X.FirstNAME= Y.FirstNAME AND X.lastNAME=Y.lastNAME AND X.dateofbirth=Y.dateofbirth
INNER JOIN table_2 Z
ON Y.customerref =Z.customerref
```

Comment: Thank you Tufan, I will give that a try and see. I've udpated my question to be clearer.

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your clarification on question just try it once

Answer (score 0):

Update SQL to below. You need to include customer_id in group by clause as well. Also you don't need to join on table 2 as your intention is to find duplicates only from table 1.

```
select cust_ref.customerId, cust_l.FirstNAME, cust_l.lastNAME, cust_l.dateofbirth
from (SELECT a.customerref, a.FirstNAME, a.lastNAME, a.dateofbirth
FROM dbo.table1 a
GROUP BY a.customerref,a.FirstNAME, a.lastNAME, a.dateofbirth
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
) cust_l
join table2 cust_ref
on cust_ref.customerref = cust_l.customerref
```

Comment: my customer id doesnt have duplicates, will group by look for duplicates in that too? Thank you Gaurav.

Comment: @EricDavid: I am not very clear with your question. In Original Post you mentioned that you want to find duplicates in "table one". In that case customer ID will also be duplicated. Is your intention to find duplicates in table 2 which has columns (customer id, customer ref,)?

Comment: I've updated my question Guarav. So in my first table, there can be duplicate entries, the customerref is unique. So what I am trying to do is find those duplicate enteries, and then take the customer ref and match it with customer id and get a list

Comment: Edited answer based on your clarification, please try that.

Comment: Something is funny, i am not getting any rows returned Gaurav. I tried the solution below and am getting the answer.